# ANT Create jarfile

Tags: java, jar, ant

I want to build a jar file using ant. 
I have a resource folder in my project with files and folder beneath.
Example:

```
Package---
             src
                    Main.java
             resources
                    images
                           logo.png
```

Inside the JAR file the images sould be accesible via `...File("resources/images/logo.png");` is that possible and if yes how?

I tried serveral options but could not figure out how it works. 
One of my attempts:

```
...    
<zipfileset dir="${dir.buildfile}/ressources/images" includes="*.png"/>
<zipfileset dir="${dir.buildfile}/ressources/images" includes="*.jpg"/>
...
```

This wasn't working...

Best regards!

Comment: Would you be okay with using a `URL` instead of a `File` object, i.e., to access your file like so: `URL url = getClass().getResource("/resources/images/logo.png");`?

Comment: Yes, that is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example. Let's say you have the following directory structure:

```
./Test.java
./Test.class
./resources/test.txt
```

where your source file accesses the file `resources/test.txt` like so:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Test {
    public void test() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/resources/test.txt");

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))) {
            for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                System.out.println("> " + line);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.test();
    }
}
```

Then the following ANT target will create a jar file that contains the `.class` file and the `resources` directory:

```
<target name="jar">
  <jar destfile="test.jar">  
    <fileset dir="." includes="Test.class"/>
    <fileset dir="." includes="resources/**"/>
  </jar>
</target>
```

You can verify that by running:

```
java -cp test.jar Test
```

Two things should be noted:

1. The `/` at the beginning of the path in the `getClass().getResource(...)` call. This is important because otherwise the package name of the class would be prepended to the given path (although in the example above, Test.java does not have a package declaration).
2. The '/**' part in the second fileset in the ANT task. Without that, only the directory itself (i.e., without any contained files) is added to your jar file.

Comment: Thank you, I will test this tomorrow when I'm back in the office.

Comment: It does not work properly. I tested it in the follwoing way: `URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resources/images/icon.png");
   BufferedImage i = ImageIO.read(url);`
But  I get a nullpointerexception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! from ImageIO.read()`

Comment: I opened a new post for that issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299812/java-getresource-image-cannot-be-found)

Comment: Did you figure the problem out in the end?

Comment: Yes, with the solution I got from the other thread I got the solution. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Was it a problem with the code in my answer, or just a matter of setting the right paths?