# Java: getResource image, cannot be found.

Tags: java, image, path

I just came up with an error in Java (using Eclipse). I want to load an image from the resource folder into the application. Using the follwoing lines:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resources/images/icon.png");
BufferedImage i = ImageIO.read(url);
```

But this results in a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!` exception.

My folder structure is:

[image: folders]

How can I access this image? Thank you a lot!

Comment: I think you don't have to include "resources" in your request (so: getResource("/images/icon.png"); )

Comment: also, if my suggestion does not work, I would suggest you to put a breakpoint and use the evaluator to make some try

Comment: Does not work, same issue.

Comment: Do you really need getClassLoader() at this point? this.getClass().getResource() works fine normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getResource()` returns `null` if it can't find the resource on the classpath.

In order to use `getResource()` you need the resources to be **on the classpath**. The resources directory isn't on the classpath. In Eclipse, you could add the `resources` folder to the classpath. Or create a new package `images` under `srcServer` and move the icon out of `resources` and into `srcServer\images` along with your source code.

Another way would be to load the image using a `File` rather than loading it as a classpath resource.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason why it doesn't find the resource is due to your syntax. `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` takes the input without the leading '/' and always starts at the root of the classpath. getClassLoader().getResource() is always an absolute path, whereas getClass().getResource() is a relative path.

Just use:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/images/icon.png");
```