# Path for getClass().getResource(path) in debug mode

Tags: java, image, debugging, path, jar

I have such piece of code

```
private Image createImage(String path)
{
    URL imageURL = getClass().getResource(path);

    if (imageURL == null)
    {
        System.err.println("Resource not found: " + path);
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return (new ImageIcon(imageURL)).getImage();
    }
}
```

When I run app using jar file, the path for `getResource()` is set to `/data/ico.png` and because inside the jar `ico.png` file located in `app.jar/data/ico.png` everything is OK and image is created.
However when I try to debug it with IDE I pass an argument to app `isdebug` based on I change the path to `..\\..\\..\\data\\ico.png`. As a result I don't find `ico.png`.
Can I even use `getResource()` in this way or I just miss the png file?
Or maybe there is some common and better way to do such things like pathes in jar/debug modes?
Dir structure is

```
src.packageA.packageB.MainClass.java
```

and ico.png is located inside

```
data\ico.png
```

===solution===
I figured out the proper path for my structure is `../../../data/ico.png` (or shortly `/data/ico.png`). In this configuration `data/ico.png` for `MyClass.class.getResource()` has to be located in `bin`.
This is important info because during launching in debug mode for Eclipse root folder is not a project one but `bin`.

Comment: Why do have a different behavior when debugging? Doesn't the same method work in both situations?

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't. Thats why I ask. Problem is with 'path' argument. Or it looks like the problem with 'path':
Resource not found: /data/ico.png
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: creating TrayIcon with null Image

Comment: That's the problem you should be trying to resolve. Is the `data` directory in the root folder? How is it added to the jar? Are you using Maven or Gradle to build the application?

Comment: Yes. `data\ico.png` in projesct is in root folder. I use Ant script to build jar: `<zipfileset dir="${WORKSPACE_DIR}\${PROJECT_NAME}\data" includes="**/*.png" prefix="data" />`.
Can you explain what is the point to analyse jar itself? This is the part that works. Maybe more important is how `getClass().getResource(path)` works? What is are the roots for different cases? But of course I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: getResource image, cannot be found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299812/java-getresource-image-cannot-be-found)

Comment: Very good link and on first look it should help but... no. I use Eclipse as an IDE and I've added `data` dir to `Debug Configuration->Dependencies->Classpath Entries->Advanced (button to the right)->Add Folders` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`..` - no. However, `getResource` allows you to start off with a slash which means the resource is looked for relative to the *root* of that classpath entry. For example, if you have in a jar this structure:

```
mypkg/MyClass.class
mypkg/icons/icon1.png
logos/logo1.png
```

(i.e. that is what you see when you run `jar tvf myjar.jar`), then you can access all of that:

```
MyClass.class.getResource("icons/icon1.png");
MyClass.class.getResource("/mypkg/icons/icon1.png");
MyClass.class.getResource("/mypkg/logos/logo1.png");
```

A few notes:

- `getClass().getResource()` is wrong. `MyClass.class.getResource()` is correct. `getClass()` breaks when you subclass. Even if *you* don't, it's not good to write fragile code.
- You do not ever use backslashes here. That's a windows thing and thus irrelevant - (even if you run your java app on windows, you'd use forward slashes. The thing you pass to getResource is a resource identifier, not a path. It's the same reason `..` is not okay in there).

Comment: I figured out the proper path for my structure is `../../../../data/ico.png`. In this configuration `ico.png` for `MyClass.class.getResource()` which is located in a.b.gui.MyClass is loaded properly. I also noticed that directory which is searched is `bin` not `src`! This important info because during launching in debug mode for Eclipse root folder is not a project folder but `bin`.

Comment: It sounds like just `/data/ico.png` is going to be a heck of a lot easier to work with. If the only point of `../../../..` is to get back to the root, just `/` does that. Of course `bin` is searched - `src` is not available at runtime (at least, not always - surely you intend for your app to be runnable without also shipping the entire source dir). I apologize for not mentioning this; I thought it was assumed.

Comment: Things make a lot more sense if you consider that your java app's "how is it actually executed" profile also needs to 'make sense' if your app is all bundled up and shipped to another system, i.e. - it is a jar file. And the `bin` dir is exactly the contents of the jar file your app will turn into when you distribute it, just, not packed up yet because that'd be a waste of resources to do during development.

Comment: Hence, when running in eclipse, that `bin` dir is the 'root'. When running as a jar, the jar is the root. And so on. Here's a useful tip: `System.out.println(SomeClass.class.getResource("SomeClass.class"));` works __everywhere__ for _any class_ (except inner classes), and tells you exactly where getResource is looking.

Comment: Is there any way to cheat IDE and replace real directory in `bin` with a shortcut? When I try to do this (under Win10) as a shoutcut I recieve `data.lnk` which is not a `data` and process fails. I suppose under Ubuntu `ls -s ...` would solve the problem but this is not an Ubuntu.

Comment: I figured it out. when in `bin` type `mklink /d "data" "..\data"`

Comment: No; `bin` is eclipse's scratch dir. You have an X/Y problem.  You have some unstated problem X and decided that solution Y ("let me replace `bin` with a shortcut!") is the answer, and are now asking questions about Y. But Y is highly unlikely to be the right answer to whatever X is.

Comment: For example, if you do 'full project clean', eclipse __will wipe that entire dir__, and your shortcut will go right along with it. Eclipse has an ability to set up dirs as source dirs (and 'compiles' non java files in source dirs by copying them over), and has an ability to link dirs, which is like shortcuts. That's possibly what you want here. What you just did is going to lead to lots of pain later.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want to do, unfortunatelly when I try to add `data` to the build path (in tab Source or Libraries) it gives me nothing. I just tried to clean the whole project and I see that indeed package path had been recreated but `data` shortcut stayed intact.